# VBA sends emails to multiple recipients

Tags: vba, excel, email

I need advice with below code. I'm stuck at point when macro check if in "Client database" Sheet client base number presented and if client by base number have different emails and  presented more than one time, lets say thrice, it sends only one mail. Instead of three different email of one client. Any ideas how to fix it?

```
Sub SendMail()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim r As Range

    Set WS1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Incomes")
    Set WS2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Client database")
    Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")

    iLastRow = WS1.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row
    oLastRow = WS2.Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row




    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            OutApp.Session.Logon


    For Each r In Worksheets("Incomes").Columns("P").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If r.Value Like "*no*" And r.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then

        match = r.Offset(0, -14).Value




       For Each cell In Worksheets("Client database").Columns("C").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)


       If cell = match Then
            nameList = cell.Offset(0, 17).Value
               On Error Resume Next
                 End If
                    Next cell


        'r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date


             'r.Value = "Yes"


            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error GoTo cleanup
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    On Error Resume Next


    With OutMail
        .To = nameList
        .Subject = "Secure: Details for Incoming Payment"
        .Body = ws3.Range("A1").Value & r.Offset(0, -7).Value
        .Display 
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
    Next r

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Actually i have two versions of these code , they both working and pursue one goal. Its my attempts to solve same task. Problem with these version is when on "Client database" sheet under matched client number there is only one email , macro gives an error

> "Run-time error"13": type mismatch"

```
Sub SendMail()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim r As Range

    Set WS1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Incomes")
    Set WS2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Client database")
    Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")

    iLastRow = WS1.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row
    oLastRow = WS2.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row




    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            OutApp.Session.Logon


    For Each r In Worksheets("Incomes").Columns("Q").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If r.Value Like "*No*" Then

        match = r.Offset(0, -14).Value

     If WS2.AutoFilterMode = False Then
        WS2.Range("A1").AutoFilter
            WS2.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
            End If



    WS2.Range("C2:C" & oLastRow).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=match

        nameList = Join(Application.Transpose(WS2.Range("T2:T" & oLastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)), ";")



        'r.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Mail sent"

             'r.Value = "Yes"


            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error GoTo cleanup
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    On Error Resume Next


    With OutMail
        .To = nameList
        .Subject = "Secure: Details for Incoming Payment"
        .Body = ws3.Range("A1").Value & r.Offset(0, -7).Value
        .Display 
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
    Next r

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If anyone is interested, here is my current working code that gives no error with one recipient and more then one.

```
Sub SendMail()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim r As Range
    Dim receiverIsOne As Boolean
    Dim countEmails As Integer

    Set WS1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Incomes")
    Set WS2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Client database")
    Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")

    iLastRow = WS1.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row
    oLastRow = WS2.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            OutApp.Session.Logon
            WS1.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Calendar.Value

    For Each r In Worksheets("Incomes").Columns("O").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If r.Value Like "no" And r.Offset(0, 9).Value = "" Or r.Offset(0, 2).Value = "No" Then
        match = r.Offset(0, -13).Value
     If WS2.AutoFilterMode = False Then
        WS2.Range("A1").AutoFilter
            WS2.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
            End If


    WS2.Range("C2:C" & oLastRow).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=match
        countEmails = WS2.Range("C2:C" & oLastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count
        If (countEmails < 2) Then
            name1 = WS2.Range("C2:C" & oLastRow).Find(match, , , xlWhole).Offset(, 17).Value
            receiverIsOne = True


        End If
        If (countEmails > 1) Then
            receiverIsOne = False
            nameList = Join(Application.Transpose(WS2.Range("T2:T" & oLastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)), ";")
            'MsgBox ("receiverIsOne = True, Count: " + countEmails)
        End If

             'r.Value = "Yes"


            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error GoTo cleanup
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    On Error Resume Next

        If (receiverIsOne) Then
            With OutMail
                .To = name1
                .Subject = "Secure -receiverIsOne " + match + "
                .Body = ws3.Range("A1").Value & r.Offset(0, -7).Value
                .Display 
            End With
        End If

        If (receiverIsOne = False) Then
            With OutMail
                .To = nameList
                .Subject = "(Secure) -receiversAreMany " + match + "
                .Body = ws3.Range("A1").Value & r.Offset(0, -7).Value
                .Display 
            End With
        End If

    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
    Next r

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `macro gives an error "Run-time error"13": type mismatch"` where? which line?

Comment: At this line:
nameList = Join(Application.Transpose(WS2.Range("T2:T" & oLastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)), ";")

Comment: there might be no visible cells in that range. debug this line and make sure that visible cell count is >0 here

Comment: Same error with " visible cell count is >0 "

Comment: You may use an answer post for an answer and as well accept that answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

This version should do what you want.

```
Make a list on the ActiveSheet with :
In column A : Names of the people
In column B : E-mail addresses
In column C : yes or no ( if the value is yes it will create a mail)
```

The Macro will loop through each row on the Activesheet and if there is a E-mail address in column B and "yes" in column C it will create a mail with a reminder like the one below for each person. If you have duplicate addresses in the column check out this example.

Dear Jelle (Jelle is a name in column A for example)

Please contact us to discuss bringing your account up to date

```
Sub Test1()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    On Error GoTo cleanup
    For Each cell In Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value) = "yes" Then

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Reminder"
                .Body = "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value _
                      & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                        "Please contact us to discuss bringing " & _
                        "your account up to date"
                'You can add files also like this
                '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
                .Send  'Or use Display
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0
            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail5.htm

Here is another great resource for you to consider.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail7.htm

Comment: Its not really a solution in my case, because i should refer on something in macro in field ".To".  And as in my case  field ".To" is floating (different clients and different emails) it should be filtered, but filter gives an error,described in main message, in case when there are only one email.

Comment: I just tested your code.  Now, I had to make some assumptions about your setup because I can't see your worksheets, but I dond't see any problems with the code.  If you want to concatenate the contents of multiple cells into one cell, try the first script mentioned below.  If you want to send an email to multiple recipients, try the second script listed below.

Answer (score 0):

' CONCATENATE CONTENTS OF MULTIPLE CELLS

```
Function ConcatRange(inputRange As Range, Optional delimiter As String) As String
    Dim oneCell As Range
    With inputRange
        If Not (Application.Intersect(.Parent.UsedRange, .Cells) Is Nothing) Then
            For Each oneCell In Application.Intersect(.Parent.UsedRange, .Cells)
                If oneCell.Text <> vbNullString Then
                    ConcatRange = ConcatRange & delimiter & oneCell.Text
                End If
            Next oneCell
            ConcatRange = Mid(ConcatRange, Len(delimiter) + 1)
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

' SEND EMAILS TO MULTIPLE RECIPIENTS

```
Dim myDelegate As Outlook.Recipient

    For Each sTo In Recipient
        Set myDelegate = OutlookMailItem.Recipients.Add(sTo)
        myDelegate.Resolve
        If Not myDelegate.Resolved Then
            myDelegate.Delete
        End If
    Next sTo

    For Each sTo In CC
        Set myDelegate = OutlookMailItem.Recipients.Add(sTo)
        myDelegate.Type = olCC
        myDelegate.Resolve
        If Not myDelegate.Resolved Then
            myDelegate.Delete
        End If
    Next sTo
```